# unnamed/slim snippets in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, code-snippets

I'm using vscode to edit latex (with the latex workshop plugin), and 
I recently started creating my own snippets and really like the feature. However, I find the syntax a bit heavy for creating "small" snippets that just abbreviate frequent sequences of words. In particular, I find it cumbersome to have to give a 'name' to each snippet.

Is there a mechanism for "slim" snippets/aliases, that would e.g. take as input a file where each snippet is one line -- the first word being the abbreviation and the rest what is abbreviated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options.  One is to write an extension that could do this - I'll show code that works like an extension that'll work - it looks complicated but use is pretty simple.

Second, you can come close using the [Hyper Snips](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=draivin.hsnips) extension where your snippet file (say `latex.hsnips`) could like like this:

```
snippet dategreeting "Gives you the current date!"
Hello from your hsnip on ``rv = new Date().toDateString()``!
endsnippet

snippet // "Fraction simple" A
\frac{$1}{$2}$0
endsnippet

snippet stte A
some text to expand
endsnippet
```

The descriptions in "" are not necessary and I eliminated it in the last snippet.  The `A` flag will immediately insert your replacement text, without it you would <kbd>Tab</kbd> to insert the replacement text.  As the examples here show you can use javascript within a snippet if you want.

The gif doesn't show it well bit here is a demo of auto-expansion with Hyper Snips:

[image: simple snippets demo 1]

---

Alternatively, download the extension [macro-commander](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jeff-hykin.macro-commander).  It allows you to use vscode extension commands in a macro within your settings.  This macro would go into your `settings.json` file:

```
"macros": {

  "slimSnippetsInsertion" : [
    { 
      "javascript": [

        "const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;",
        "const document = editor.document;",
        "const we = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();",
      
        "const cursorPosition = editor.selection.active;",   // use whether an actual selection or not, returns a Position
        "let keyWordRange = document.getWordRangeAtPosition(cursorPosition);",  // returns a Range of start/end Positions or undefined
        "if (keyWordRange === undefined) {",
          "await window.showInformationMessage(`cursor must be in or immediately after word to be replaced`);",
          "return;",
        "}",

        "let wordAtCursor = document.getText(keyWordRange);",  // this is the key word to find in slimSnippets.txt

        "const thisWorkspace = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri.toString();",
                // file:///c:/Users/Mark/OneDrive/Test Bed

        "const snippetFileContent = await vscode.workspace.fs.readFile(vscode.Uri.parse(`${thisWorkspace}/.vscode/slimSnippets.txt`));",

        "const snippets = snippetFileContent.toString();",

                    // ignore leading spaces/tabs before keys
                    // using a named capturing group for the replacement text
        "const regex = new RegExp(`\\r?(?<=\\n|^)[\\t ]*(?<key>${wordAtCursor})[\\t ]+?(?<replacementText>.*?)(?=\\r?\\n|$)`);",

        "let found = snippets.match(regex);",  // returns null if no matches

        // matched a key but only spaces as replacement text, so do nothing and exit
        "if (found && found.groups.replacementText.trimStart().length === 0) {",
          "await window.showInformationMessage(`replacement text is only spaces, not replacing`);",
          "return;",
        "}",

        "if (found) {",                      // found at least a matching key
          "if (found.groups.replacementText) {",  // found non-space replacement text

            // replace `\n` and `\t` with unicode values for newline and tab
            "let replace = found.groups.replacementText.replace(/\\\\n/g, '\\u000A').replace(/\\\\t/g, '\\u0009');",
            "let snippet = new vscode.SnippetString(replace)",

            "if (editor.selections.length === 1) editor.insertSnippet(snippet, keyWordRange);",  // if zero or one selection"
                 // if multiple selections, uses first key and replacement text"
            "else editor.insertSnippet(snippet);",
          "}",
          "else await window.showInformationMessage(`matching key found but with no replacement text in slimSnippets.txt`);",
        "}",
        "else await window.showInformationMessage(`no matching key found in slimSnippets.txt`);",
    ]
}
```

You can see where I made it to read a `simpleSnippets.txt` file located in the `.vscode` folder in the workspace - but you can change the location as long as you alter the path info in the command: `vscode.workspace.fs.readFile` above.

The `slimSnippets.txt` file is just a simple text file where the first word in each line is the `key` and the rest of the line is the replacement.

```
howdy1 $1 first $2 sentence with tabstops
howdy1 this won't be used, duplicate key above

howdy2 second sentence with variable $TM_FILENAME

key3    videos 111111    // one space necessary between key and replacement text
                     //     it will be removed, others retained
key1 222222

stte some text to expand
mt2e more text to expand


  [replacement text can have placeholders, tabstops and choices just like regular snippets]

  [join multiple-lines snippets into one string with newlines as below]
  [some text\nsome more text] [\t can be used for tabs]

 key5 line 1\n\tline 2\n\t\tline 3
```

Keys are single words and if there is no replacement text (or there are only spaces in the file after a key) nothing will happen - the key will not be replaced.

The text actually inserted can be plain text or use vscode's snippet format - see the sample text file above.

[image: demo of macro with snippets]

The cursor must be immediately after the word or in the word and the word can be selected or not.  It must be a word in the regex sense - not continuous text adjoining the word before or after it - just a standalone word, it can be anywhere on the line.

If you have duplicate keys, the first will be used.  There can be empty line spaces between key/replacement lines or not.

You will not get intellisense for the keys.  I may work on that.

Finally, you will need a keybinding to trigger this macro (in `keybindings.json`):

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+;",             // whatever keybinding you wish
  "command": "macros.slimSnippetsInsertion"
},
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great! I'll start by trying the hypersnips