# How to make code snippet shortcuts in VS Code work like IntelliJ live templates?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

While i used IntelliJ , i could just type 'sout' and intellij would just expand it to 'System.out.println'.
I could just type psvm , and IntelliJ would expand it to 'public static void main' .
I am looking for the same shortcuts in vscode, but not able to get it, even after installing the IntelliJ IDEA Keybindings- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.intellij-idea-keybindings.
Is there a vscode extension that i need to install to get it ?
Or is there some other trick that i am missing ?

Comment: watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_QshKsUXO8

Comment: This worked for me !

Comment: Why don't you answer your own question? Describe what you did with complete code for others who may come across the same problem. This is how you can give back to the community. Thanks.

Comment: Sure @Doc, here it is.  

Go to Preferences >> User Snippets >> Select Java.  
Copy paste the following   

`"sout": {
  
  "prefix": "sout",
  "body": ["System.out.println(\" \");"]
},
"psv": {
  "prefix": "psv",
  "body": ["public static void main(String[] args){}"]
}`

Comment: If u need a snippet generator https://snippet-generator.app/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60997320/unnamed-slim-snippets-in-vscode/64421337#64421337 and the HyperSnips example.

Comment: @wingsforever - FYI, you could post that as an answer instead of a comment if you’re so inclined. Might need to wait a day, though, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

The [solution posted by @wingsforever works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61382852/how-to-make-code-snippet-shortcuts-in-vs-code-work-like-intellij-live-templates/67680324#comment108612782_61382852). Just adding image for anyone to easy follow:

[image]

This way we can make any code snippet or custom tag.