# manage VScode snippet dictionary

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just learn how to manage a snippet in VSCode and found a tutorial that show without any extra plugins, and it works. here is my snippets so far.

```
{
    // Place your global snippets here. Each snippet is defined under a snippet name and has a scope, prefix, body and
    // description. Add comma separated ids of the languages where the snippet is applicable in the scope field. If scope
    // is left empty or omitted, the snippet gets applied to all languages. The prefix is what is
    // used to trigger the snippet and the body will be expanded and inserted. Possible variables are:
    // $1, $2 for tab stops, $0 for the final cursor position, and ${1:label}, ${2:another} for placeholders.
    // Placeholders with the same ids are connected.
    // Example:
    "Print to console": {
        "scope": "javascript,typescript",
        "prefix": "mantap",
        "body": [
            "console.log('$1');",
            "$2"
        ],
        "description": "Log output to console"
    },
    "css font size": {
        "scope": "css, scss",
        "prefix": "fs",
        "body": [
            "font-size: $1px;",
            "$2"
        ],
        "description": "uwak kawu"

    },
    "zindex": {
        "scope": "css, scss",
        "prefix": "z",
        "body": [
            "z-index: $1;",
            "$2"
        ],
        "description": "uwak kawu"
    },
    "cp": {
        "scope": "css, scss",
        "prefix": "cpn",
        "body": [
            "cursor: pointer;",
        ],
        "description": "uwak ka;.wu"
    }
}
```

as you can see just to add a simple snippet I have to add 8 lines, is there any other options (extensions is ok) that can I use to get this simpler, like no matter what workspace I'm working at as long as I type "a" it will suggest "an apple" then I can manage the dictionary as simple way like:

```
{
    "a": "an apple"
}
```

Comment: you can write your own code completion provider and read your simplified syntax

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64421337/836330 same question.